# How to add overlay on the webrtc using frozen mountain icelink in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, overlay, webrtc, websync

I am developing a video streaming iOS app using Frozen mountain icelink library , How can I add overlays to the screen which will be broadcasted to all other peers which are connected to the same session  (i.e overlay should be reflected in realtime)

Comment: You mean overlays which will be reflected frequently according to video streaming?

Comment: @ Kiran Jasvanee  thanx for your time, exactly that is what I want to acheive